# rxjs forkJoin does not stop subsequent requests after an error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

The problem is that queries in the forkjoin array continue to execute even if the previous one failed. For example, already in the first request putCategory$ an error occurred (the name already exists). However, the next loadImage$ request is executed and the new image is still loaded. Why? How to make a sequence of requests so that if a failure occurs, the next ones will not be executed?

```
 PUTCategory(category: ICategory) {
    const newImage = category.image;
    const oldImage = this.editedCategory.image;
    const imageChanged = oldImage !== newImage;
    const loadImage = imageChanged && !!newImage;
    const deleteImage = imageChanged && !!oldImage;

    const file: File = this.form.value.image;

    const putCategory$ = this.categoryService.putCategory(category).pipe(
      catchError((response: any) => {
        if (response.error.info == 'NAME_EXISTS') {
          this.throwErrorModal(
            'Категория с таким названием уже существует. Измените название и попробуйте снова.',
          );
        } else {
          this.throwErrorModal(
            'Произошла ошибка при попытке обновить категорию',
          );
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );

    const loadImage$ = loadImage
      ? this.categoryService.uploadCategoryImage(file).pipe(
          catchError(() => {
            this.throwErrorModal(
              'Произошла ошибка при попытке загрузить файл нового изображения категории',
            );
            return EMPTY;
          }),
          concatMap((response: any) => {
            const filename = response.filename;
            return this.categoryService
              .setImageToCategory(category.id, filename)
              .pipe(
                catchError(() => {
                  this.throwErrorModal(
                    'Произошла ошибка при попытке связать новое загруженное изображение и категорию',
                  );
                  return EMPTY;
                }),
              );
          }),
        )
      : of(null);

    const deleteImage$ = deleteImage
      ? this.categoryService.deleteImage(oldImage!).pipe(
          catchError(() => {
            this.throwErrorModal(
              'Произошла ошибка при попытке удалить старое изображение категории',
            );
            return EMPTY;
          }),
          concatMap(() => {
            return this.categoryService
              .setImageToCategory(category.id, '')
              .pipe(
                catchError(() => {
                  this.throwErrorModal(
                    'Произошла ошибка при попытке удаления связи старого изображения с категорией',
                  );
                  return EMPTY;
                }),
              );
          }),
        )
      : of(null);

    forkJoin([putCategory$, deleteImage$, loadImage$])
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.awaitModal = false;
          this.cdr.markForCheck();
        }),
        tap(() => {
          this.successModal = true;
        }),
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Just in case, throwErrorModal is my simple function

```
 private throwErrorModal(content: string) {
    this.errorModalContent = content;
    this.errorModal = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) waits for all observables to emit a value or errors and completes.
You are using `catchError` to catch any error from the API, and this is the reason why `forkJoin` doesn't unsubscribe from the other streams.
You could `throw` a new error after having displayed the modal so that the other streams are blocked.

```
    const putCategory$ = this.categoryService.putCategory(category).pipe(
      catchError((response: any) => {
        if (response.error.info == 'NAME_EXISTS') {
          this.throwErrorModal(
            'Категория с таким названием уже существует. Измените название и попробуйте снова.',
          );
        } else {
          this.throwErrorModal(
            'Произошла ошибка при попытке обновить категорию',
          );
        }
        throw new Error("error message")
      }),
    );
```

---

Keep in mind that using `forkJoin`, the 3 API calls will be executed asynchronously, thus you cannot know if one completes (or errors) before the other. If you use it there could be a scenario where `deleteImage$` or `loadImage$` complete before `putCategory$` has the chance to throw an error.
So if the other observables needs to depend on the result of `putCategory$`, you could pipe the latter, and return the `forkJoin` of the formers in a `switchMap`:

```
putCategory$.pipe(
  // Here `putCategory` has done its job
  switchMap( () => forkJoin([deleteImage$, loadImage$])),
  // Here the other observables have completed and have been executed asynchronously
  // But only if putCategory hasn't thrown any errors
  finalize(() => {
    this.awaitModal = false;
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }),
  tap(() => {
    this.successModal = true;
  }),
)
```